# Lua with Traditional Chinese

Tags: string, unicode, lua

I convert some lua script(it contains chinese character) from simplified chinese to traditional chinese, and now the chinese character is encoding with cp950.

Now I switch my win7 machine locale to zh_TW, and restart. Everything seems okay, the script with traditional chinese character is correct displayed.

But when I complied these script.It is error.Invalid escape string.

for example:

```
msg="外功系普攻攻擊"
print(msg)
```

the result is:

外巨t普攻攻擊

Look at the hex of the string, it is

```
\xa5~\xa5\\\xa8t\xb4\xb6\xa7\xf0\xa7\xf0\xc0\xbb
```

so it is the lua not escape the string.

Now the problem is, can I solve it? How can I let the script compile success? My source script can not encoding into utf-8, if can, it is esay.

Comment: What version of Lua are you using? I tried to run the same script on my Windows machine and it outputs the correct message (`外功系普攻攻擊` instead of `外巨t普攻攻擊`).

Comment: The version is 5.1.4. Have you switch the system locale to zh_TW?

Comment: I use Win10 **en_US** with **Lua 5.4.2**, it show 外功系普攻攻擊. Looks good.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very very famous cp950 (Big5) encoding problem called "許功蓋" issue, see http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%94%E7%A2%BC

So utf8 is the the best slove to it.